# With English, French and Spanish enabled. Recently our Comms folks can't add translations

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

We're using Drupal 9.4.10 - turned on content translation for the Comms role for all content types, URLs, etc. but that role cannot create translations for any content type. They can edit the translations after they're created by an Administrator. Other than giving them Admin permissions does anyone have any ideas about how this could be?

They can actually click on Add translation then fill in the translated content, but when trying to save the translation, the error is Either the path '/node/x'is invalid or you do not have access to it.

[image]

Comment: You can create a role specifically allowing just content translation, and assign those roles to these users. This way, you don't have to assign the administrator role to everyone. It's not uncommon to create a "Content Editor" role whose permissions only involve content creation/editing/translation and none related to site management.

Comment: The Comms role already has all of the Content translation permissions. I've also rebuilt permissions in case it was a caching thing.

Comment: This sounds very similar, are you using the view_unpublished module? Thats mentioned https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3101344

Comment: Yes we are (recently installed it so all Comms folks could view each other's work)! Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved at least for now, by giving Link to any page permission to our Comms role (as noted in the issue).

The only side effect with this is that the Comms folks now see all menu items that they don't have access to, so not ideal.